# Crystal Reports:IF/THEN/ELSE with null values and multiple conditions

Tags: sql, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2013, winsql

I am new to crystal reports and am writing a formula for crystal so I can get a check for when certain trainings are due and every training has a different due date. For example if someone was hired 9/1/2022, they would have 15 days for report training, 30 days for the exposure training, etc.

And if the training is null, we want to print the due date of the training. So using the example report training would be due 9/16/2022.

My statement is something like this:

```
IF ISNULL({command.step1) AND ISNULL({@15 day check) THEN {command.15DayDue}
IF ISNULL({command.step1) AND ISNULL({@30 day check) THEN {command.30DayDue}
ELSE ToText({command.step1},'MM/dd/yyyy')
```

I keep running into an error message saying that the last line isn't part of the formula. I'm struggling a bit because I am not sure how to get all the conditions in the same formula field.

Comment: Should the `OR` be an `ELSE IF` instead?

Comment: Ive tried the OR statement as well and get the same error message.

Comment: I'm not sure were saying the same thing? I was suggesting (as psuedo code) `IF step1 AND 15 day THEN 15 ELSE IF step1 AND 30 day THEN 30 ELSE '05/20/2022'`

Answer (score 0):

Before the question was edited, the code was:

```
IF ISNULL({command.step1) AND ISNULL({@15 day check) THEN {command.15DayDue}
OR ISNULL({command.step1) AND ISNULL({@30 day check) THEN {command.30DayDue}
ELSE ToText({command.step1},'MM/dd/yyyy')
```

Suggested changing the `OR` to an `ELSE IF`:

```
IF ISNULL({command.step1) AND ISNULL({@15 day check) THEN {command.15DayDue}
ELSE IF ISNULL({command.step1) AND ISNULL({@30 day check) THEN {command.30DayDue}
ELSE ToText({command.step1},'MM/dd/yyyy')
```